# KOMA-Script and quote environments in footnotes

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, paragraphs, quoting, legal-style

I'm trying to properly typeset an inline citation following a `quote` environment embedded in a footnote in both `scrlttr2` and `scrartcl`. This is necessary to properly accomplish certain aspects of *Bluebook*-style citations. The following MWE works as expected in `article` and `memoir` but is broken in `scrartcl`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} % or {article} or {memoir}
\begin{document}
Text.\footnote{This is some footnote text that leads into a quotation. As the
first line of a paragraph, it should have a different amount of indentation
compared to subsequent lines.
\begin{quote}
This is a block quote, which has the same degree of indentation across all
lines. Although this environment appears to work as expected, there is clearly
some problem as the subsequent lines demonstrate.
\end{quote}
The Author, \emph{The Article}, 2~\textsc{Some L.J.} 110, 110 (2016). This is a
citation that is part of the same paragraph. It should have the same
indentation as the other subsequent lines.  It should not behave as a new
paragraph.\par
This is a new paragraph of text. It should, as such, have the same indentation
as the first line of this footnote, and each subsequent line should have normal
indentation.}
\end{document}
```

Result in `scrartcl`:
[image: Screenshot of scrartcl version at Imgur]
Intended formatting in `article` and `memoir`, respectively:
[image: Screenshot of article version at Imgur]
[image: Screenshot of memoir version at Imgur]

This is also broken in `scrlttr2`, which is what I *actually* care about, but because it's still broken (in a different way) in `letter`, I'm comparing these classes.

Comment: it is not broken, but simply different. Check \deffootnote in the documentation if you want to change the style.

Comment: Unfortunately,`\deffootnote` does not address the behavior here. What I want is for the line immediately following a `quote` environment *not* to indent to `parindent` without a `\par`, because I do not intend a new paragraph. `\deffootnote` does not appear to address this behavior.

Comment: I should also note that this behavior *only* occurs within a `footnote`. It behaves as expected in normal body text in all three document classes.

Comment: I see no indentation in your pictures. "The Author" is clearly not identated like "This is a new ...".

Comment: It seems to be a bug. The line after the `quote` environment is intented by `mark width` which is set in the optional argument of `\deffootnote`. Example: `\deffootnote[4em]{0pt}{1.5em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}`

Comment: @esdd: Yes, exactly! It should not be indented by `mark width`, but by `indent`. Even if we presume that after `quote` we want to start a new paragraph, it should be indented by `parindent` rather than `mark width`. This image provides an exaggerated example of what the problem is, as shown by playing with `deffootnote`: [Example image](http://i.imgur.com/US3SKZC.png). The only workaround I can see is to make all indents equal, which is highly undesirable from a typesetting perspective.

Comment: I have reported the issue to Markus Kohm. Very old/historical code is responsible for the problem and Markus needs some time to fix it. Maybe your issue will delay the next KOMA-Script version ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the [current pre-release of KOMA-Script 3.22](http://www.komascript.de/current) your example produces:

[image]

The [list of known bugs of release 3.21 (in German)](http://www.komascript.de/release3.21) has an entry:

> - Listen und davon abgeleitete Umgebungen innerhalb von Fußnoten beeinflussen den Einzug nach der Umgebung in unerwarteter Weise.
>     Bemerkung: Ich halte wenig von Fußnotenapparaten, die derart ausufern, dass darin der Einsatz von Listen sinnvoll wäre. Aber die Leute, die das machen, interessiert das ja leider nicht.
>     Hinweis: Ab [KOMA-Script v3.22.2571](http://www.komascript.de/current) wird eine komplett neue Methode für die Ausgabe der Fußnoten verwendet, soweit nicht Kompatibilität zu eine KOMA-Script-Version kleiner 3.22 eingestellt ist.

In English:

> - Lists and derived environments inside footnotes influence the indent behind the environment unexpectedly.
>     Remark: …
>     Note: From [KOMA-Script v3.22.2571](http://www.komascript.de/current) a new method is used for the output of footnotes, if compatibility to KOMA-Script less than 3.22 has not been selected.

So I think, the problem is already fixed.